# ruby on rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
    def remove_items
    line_items.each do |item|
        @ci = Product.find(item.id)
        @ci.quantity = @ci.quantity.to_i - 1
end
```

Hello, I am trying to use the id of the item and then match the id with a product and then minus 1 to the quantity property of that product.

I currently get this error though.

```
TypeError in OrdersController#create

can't convert nil into String
```

What is wrong?
Thanks

OrderController#create
Please bear in mind code is scruffy due to being in progress. :)

```
def create
@order = current_cart.build_order(params[:order])
@order.ip_address = request.remote_ip
@cart = current_cart

  if @order.save
      if @order.purchase
        @order.status = "paid"                      
        @cart.remove_items          
        @cart.destroy
        render :action => "success"
      else
      @order.status = "failed"
      @cart.destroy
         render :action => "failure"
    end
  else
    render action: "new"        
  end
```

end

I think this is the stack trace

```
[0m
  ←[1m←[35mLineItem Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WH
ERE "line_items"."cart_id" = 129
  ←[1m←[36mProduct Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHE
RE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1←[0m  [["id", 147]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5762ms

TypeError (can't convert nil into String):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:60:in `+'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:60:in `record_not_found'
```

Comment: post the full action in your controller and the stacktrace.

Comment: Show us action of `create` on `OrdersController` and output of `rake routes`

Comment: Added OrderController. Will get rake routes now

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace for the error?

Comment: Posted what I think is the stack trace. Thanks

Comment: The error is in app/controllers/application_controller.rb line 60, can you post the code from there?

Comment: What version of Rails are you running?

Comment: def record_not_found
  flash[:alert] = "Cannot find record number " + params[:id] + ". Displaying all records."
  redirect_to root_path 
 end

Comment: I am running the latest rails version

Comment: @baihu added an answer based on your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment this should solve the problem:

```
# application_controller.rb
def record_not_found
  flash[:alert] = "Cannot find record number #{params[:id]}. Displaying all records." 
  redirect_to root_path 
end
```

But if I were you I wouldn't output the params[:id] in the alert message. Just say that the record has not been found, basta.

```
flash[:alert] = "Cannot find record. Displaying all records."
```

You can also do this in one line:

```
redirect_to root_path, alert: "Cannot find record. Displaying all records."
```

---

To fix the logic in your `remove_items` method you need to actually save the object at the end:

```
def remove_items
    line_items.each do |item|
        ci = Product.find(item.id)
        ci.quantity = ci.quantity.to_i - 1
        ci.save
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the error but the logic does not work. Even when I hard code this, nothing changes

  def remove_items
   [at]ci = Product.find(10)
   [at]ci.quantity = 0
  end

Is there an issue with the instance of the object or the actual syntax itself?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're buding a shopping cart app from scratch. Have you considered using an existing platform, like Spree?

Comment: I didn't know such a thing existed but I like the experience of building something myself anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's a better idea to have the DB decrement all the Products at once:

```
def remove_items
    Product.where(id:line_items.map(&:id)).update_all('quantity = quantity - 1')
end
```

OR even better:

```
def remove_items
    Product.decrement_counter(:quantity, line_items.map(&:id) )
end
```

These are faster, avoid errors if the product can not be found, and also avoid a [Race Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Example) if you have multiple processes running concurrently.